# Why does one have to use warm water with water flossers (e.g., Waterpik)?

Tags: dentistry, floss-flossing

I read in a few places that one has to use warm water with water flossers (e.g., Waterpik). Why wouldn't cold water be ok too?

E.g., from https://www.waterpik.com/oral-health/blog/waterpik-mouthwash/ ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20181111222737/https://www.waterpik.com/oral-health/blog/waterpik-mouthwash/)):

> all you need in your Water Flosser for clinically proven effectiveness is warm water

---

I have crossposted the question at:

- https://qr.ae/TUhgFe
- https://redd.it/9w86i3

Comment: What has your research shown you already?

Comment: I've used a Waterpik, and I know from experience that using cold water can simply be uncomfortable, especially if your tap water is fairly cold, as mine is since it's well water. I seriously doubt that temperature of the water matters in the least to the device's effectiveness. It's just a comfort factor.

Comment: @JohnP many guides advise to use warm water but I haven't seen any that explain why

Comment: From personal experience using a water pik with cold water can be really painful, its like icy needles poking into your gums! Use warm water so it doesn’t hurt unnecessarily.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Comfort factor only.

> Chat session started at 9:16:01
>
> Thank you for contacting Waterpik. One of our customer service representatives will be with you in just a moment.
>
> You are now chatting with Aleecia
>
> Aleecia :Thank you for contacting Water Pik, my name is Aleecia. How can I help you today?
>
> Ted:Why is it recommended to use warm water in the flosser?
>
> Ted:"all you need in your Water Flosser for clinically proven effectiveness is warm water"
>
> Ted:Where is the study proving the clinical effectiveness?
>
> Aleecia :I would be glad to help answer. We recommend warm water as to not cause unnecessary irritation.
>
> Ted:How is warm water more clinically effective than other temperatures?
>
> Ted:Or is the clinical effectiveness independent of the temperature, and warm water is only recommended for the comfort factor?
>
> Aleecia :The only reason why we recommend using warm water is because it may cause less irritation. Purely a comfort factor.